# Yii YiiMailer not found

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am using an extension in Yii called YiiMailer. I have used it in my commands and it has worked fine and loading also works fine. Now I want to use it in one of my controllers and I keep getting

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'YiiMailer' not found in

I have it setup in my imports array inside my config file. Both in the main and the console app. Any idea why I cannot use this extension from a controller? I know it works right because like I said it works in the console app.

Extension can be found here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimailer/

Answer (score 0):

I guess it was a permission issues the web user was unable to access it but my console user was.